# why to use function to define a property?

Tags: javascript

i read about `defineProperty()`.

but i found this notation in a program i don't understand:

```
myObject.defineProperty("something", "propertyNameExample", function()
{
// function body here
})
```

what i do not understand is that `function() {...}` notation.

what role does it play for "propertyNameExample"?

please explain me. thank you

Comment: It's a function. Maybe taking a step back and spinning through some JS basics, particularly how functions can be (a) anonymous, and (b) passed around as values, would be a good idea.

Comment: What `defineProperty` method is that? Show us the code that creates/defines `myObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing (or technically not sure), this is not a native method for defining a property in Javsacript.

There are two things wrong here

- It should be `Object.defineProperty` not `myObject.defineProperty`
- `myObject.defineProperty` will be a user defined function not a native function.

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), third argument is a **descriptor object** not a `function`.

Even if you pass a function as the parameter, it doesn't affect the functionality in any way, whether you are setting a property or getting a property.

Comment: The code that the OP has shown doesn't look like `Object.defineProperty` at all

Comment: @Bergi that is true, it looks like a more custom method than the native `Object.defineProperty`